# how to limit growing of textarea using css or jquery after max-height?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Can anyone tell how to limit the growing of textarea on typing?? I tried using max-height property but no use...the textarea keeps on growing more than the page-height.

Comment: I guess, you would want to set `height` of `textarea`

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('keydown','textarea',function(){
        // you can change window to your container
        if($(window).height()==$(this).height())
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry.. i forgot to mention. resizing is needed but only till the page is filled i.e if the size of textarea has reached the size of the page it shoul stop allowing to type and stop growing.

Comment: @user1844039 check the above code for stopping any one if `height` is `maximized`.

Comment: it's working with textarea created statically. but it's not working with textarea's created dynamically.. why is it not working?

Comment: @user1844039 test the above I've made changes in it. Read http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: @NikhilPatil If you know then `Jquery 1.9` has removed `live` function as `jquery.on()` can handle easily in place of `live`. Read http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: @RohanKumar Sorry, you're right. I did not see the deprecation

Comment: even now its not working..what is the problem with dynamically created elements? why is the behavior different?

Comment: I am using jquery mobile. Is that the problem?

Comment: May be this is the problem but have you added any version of `jquery`. If yes then use `jquery version 1.8 of above`